# printing exclusive multiplication of two numbers under 100

Tags: c, loops

> **3-9. Print the exclusive multiple of two numbers**
>
> After inputting two numbers, print out all the numbers from 1 to 100 that are multiples of only one of the two numbers. That is, a number that is a common multiple of the two numbers should not be output.
>
> For example, if 15 and 20 are input, "15, 20, 30, 40, 45, 75, 80, 90, 100" is output. (60 is not in the output)
>
> For loops, use the 'for' statement, and use variables as follows.
>
> ```
> int num1, num2; // two numbers entered
> int i; // variable for iteration
> ```
>
> **Example of execution)**
>
> ```
> Enter 2 numbers 15 20
> 15
> 20
> 30
> 40
> 45
> 75
> 80
> 90
> 100
> ```

I recently started to learn c programming and this is the question I have tried to solve the question but my code does not work properly can somebody help me with this question? thank you so much

this is the code I have tried

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int num1,num2;
  int i=1;
  int result1;
  int result2;
  printf("Enter 2 numbers \n");
  scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
  for(i=1;i>0;i++){
    if(num1*i<=100&&num2*i<=100){
      if((num1*i%num2!=0)&&(num2*i%num1!=0)){
        printf("%d\n",num1*i);
        printf("%d\n",num2*i);
        }
      else if((num2*i%num1==0)&&(num1*i%num2!=0))
        printf("%d\n",num1*i);
      else if((num1*i%num2==0)&&(num2*i%num1!=0))
        printf("%d\n",num2*i);
      
      }
    else if((num1*i>100&&num2*i<=100)&& (num2*i%num1!=0&&num1*i%num2==0))
        printf("%d\n",num2*i);
    else if((num2*i>100&&num1*i<=100)&&(num1*i%num2!=0&&num2*i%num1==0))
        printf("%d\n",num1*i);
```

Comment: If you want us to fix the code, you need to show the code, too.

Comment: `for(i=1; i>0; i++)` That condition will be `true` for a loooong time...

Comment: It seems that you are overcomplicating things. As a first approach you could just iterate over all the numbers between 1 and 100 and if `i` is divisible by only one of the two numbers (have you learned about "exclusive or"?), print `i`.

Comment: I am so sorry for this it is my first time using the website I am sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the end of the `main` function is missing
- the loop `for(i=1;i>0;i++)` is an infinite loop. You should instead loop from 1 to 100 and check if the number is a multiple of `num1`, `num2`, but not both.
- using white space after keywords, commas and semicolons and on both sides of binary operators makes the code much more readable.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, num1, num2;
    printf("Enter 2 numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2) != 2) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (num1 <= 0 || num2 <= 0) {
        printf("invalid numbers\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i % num1 == 0 || i % num2 == 0) {
            /* i is a multiple of num1 or num2 */
            if (!(i % num1 == 0 && i % num2 == 0)) {
                /* i is a not a multiple of both num1 and num2 */
                printf("%d\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a more compact version suggested by [Gerhardh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782754/gerhardh):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, num1, num2;
    printf("Enter 2 numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2) != 2) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (num1 <= 0 || num2 <= 0) {
        printf("invalid numbers\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if ((i % num1 == 0) != (i % num2 == 0)) {
            /* i is a multiple of num1 or num2 but not both */
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `if ((i % num1 == 0) != (i % num2 == 0))` without relying on int values.

Comment: thank you so much for the help. It is my first time using this website so I made the code hard to read. I am sorry and thank you so much for the help

Comment: @Gerhardh: very good point! Answer amended.

Comment: @jaeyoonKim: no problem, finding answers and improving one's skills is exactly what SO is for. Improved readability benefits every reader, including yourself! Keep learning and enjoy programming.

Comment: @jaeyoonKim You don't get the point. You shall not only make the code readable **for us**. You shall make it more readable **for you** as well. You will have to read own code far more often than you will write it. After a few weeks you will be glad if you have formatted properly.

Comment: what does if ((i % num1 == 0) + (i % num2 == 0) == 1) in the code? I am sorry I don't know about programming

Comment: @jaeyoonKim: `(i % num1 == 0)` has a value `1` if the comparison is true and `0` otherwise... so adding these values computes the number of successful comparisons, which must be exactly `1` for your purpose.  Gerhardh proposed a cleaner version by comparing the results of both comparisons: if they differ, then exactly one comparison is true, which is enough for the program goal.

Comment: @chqrlie oh ok. so does this mean ((i % num1 == 0) != (i % num2 == 0)) i only divide by either num1 or num2 but not both?

Comment: @jaeyoonKim no. How would you know if they yield same result if you don't evaluate both sides?

Answer (score 2):

[chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73784356/4944425) shows an optimal implementation of the algorithm hinted by the problem statement.

> For loops, use the 'for' statement, and use variables as follows.
>
> ```
> int num1, num2; // two numbers entered
> int i; // variable for iteration
> ```

The asker, though, seems to have tried a different approach, using `i` to directly calculate the multiples of `num1` and `num2` and somehow compare only those numbers to decide what to print.

I like the idea of considering only the multiples instead of all the numbers up to 100, but the posted implementation has many issues.

- Is incomplete and rather confusing.
- The loop has an always `true` condition (until `i` overflows, then it's UB), making it endless, without any `break` statements.
- In the body, `if( num1 * i <= 100  &&  num2 * i <= 100 )`, excludes all the possible results where only one of the multiples is less than the limit.
- The outputted numbers are not presented in ascending order, which seems to be a requirement of the exercise.

I would have introduced another variable (note, that seems not what the problem statement suggests) to simplify the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/xTTcnPnoz).

```
int const limit = 100;
for ( int i = num1, j = num2    // 'i' are the multiples of 'num1', 'j' of 'num2'.
    ; i <= limit || j <= limit  // The loop stops when BOTH are over the limit.
    ;                           // <- No increment here.
    ) {
  if ( i < j ) {          // Note that this ensures it doesn't exceed the limit.
    printf("%d\n", i);         
    i += num1;            // Next multiple.
  }
  else if ( j < i ) {
    printf("%d\n", j);
    j += num2;
  }
  else {        // They may exceed the limit, here, but nothing is printed.
    i += num1;
    j += num2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, much more efficient, with just a potential UB if `limit` were greater than `INT_MAX - num1` or `INT_MAX - num2`. I cannot think of a simple fix for this, especially if `limit == INT_MAX`.

Comment: @chqrlie True. If the input is signed I'd just assert `(unsigned)INT_MAX <= UINT_MAX - INT_MAX` and use `unsigned` in the [calculations](https://godbolt.org/z/qTTqeq9ex) or a wider type. If it's already an unsigned type, well, yeah, it's not easily [fixable](https://godbolt.org/z/K1afsrYn5).

Answer (score 1):

Another way: Capriciously using an array of 32 bit int's for no more than 'flags'.
Merely set these flags for the 'harmonics' of one number,
then sweep up the 'harmonics' of the other checking and flushing flags from the former and suppressing common values.

This consumes memory, but might be faster than quite a few base10 modulo calculations.
The memory issue could be addressed with bit fields (perhaps 25 bits for 32 bit systems and 50 bits on 64 bit systems).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    for( ;; ) {
        int i, ilag, n1, n2, arr[ 1 + 100 ]; // base 1 numbering

        printf( "Enter 2 numbers \n" );
        if( scanf( "%d %d", &n1, &n2 ) != 2
        ||  n1 == n2
        ||  !(1 < n1 && n1 <= 100)
        ||  !(1 < n2 && n2 <= 100)
            )
            exit(1);

        memset( arr, 0, sizeof arr );
        for( i = n1; i <= 100; i += n1 ) arr[ i ] = i;
        ilag = 1;
        for( i = n2; i <= 100; i += n2 ) {
            for( ; ilag < i; ilag++ )
                if( arr[ ilag ] )
                    printf( "%d ", ilag );
            if( i != arr[ ilag++ ] )
                printf( "%d ", i );
        }
        puts( "" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Enter 2 numbers
15 20
15 20 30 40 45 75 80 90 100
Enter 2 numbers
6 9
6 9 12 24 27 30 42 45 48 60 63 66 78 81 84 96 99
Enter 2 numbers
```

Comment: Good approach too... How about these simpler loops: `for( i = n1; i <= 100; i += n1 ) arr[ i ]++;` `for( i = n2; i <= 100; i += n2) arr[ i ]++;` `for( i = 1; i <= 100; i++ ) { if (arr[ i ] == 1) printf("%d\n", i); }`

Comment: @chqrlie THAT is pretty-much what I was hoping to get to eventually... Much simpler! Thanks... Suggest you add that to your answer as an alternative approach... Great stuff `:-)`